# An algebraic topology problem with the fundamental group

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, algebraic-topology

Show that there is $F⊂[0,1]×[0,1]$  closed and
$f:F→S^1$  continuous that does not admit a continuous extension
$g:[0,1]×[0,1]→S^1$.

I tried to solve that problem with properties of homotopy and fundamental group, but I have found difficulties to relate those things

Comment: Your title and your text do not agree.

Comment: Tietze's theorem holds (at least) in any locally compact Hausdorff space. This example shows that it does not hold for $S^1$-valued functions...

Comment: Do you know the no-retraction theorem?

Comment: I think this title is worse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The square $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ is homeomorphic to the disk $D^2 = \{ \xi \in \mathbb R^2 \mid \lVert \xi \rvert \le 1\}$. Thus you question is equivalent to

> Show that there is
> $F
> ⊂
> D^2$
> closed and
> $f
> :
> F
> →
> S
> ^
> 1
> $
> continuous that does not admit a continuous extension
> $
> g
> :
> D^2 →
> S
> ^
> 1
> $.

Take $F = S^1$ and $f = id$. If $f$ had an extension $g : D^2 \to S^1$, $g$ would be null-homotopic, which is not true.